# Generate table with columns dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql

Say we have a table named questions with the following schema and content

```
id | name | text
1  | Q1   | Java: some text
2  | Q2   | Python: other text
3  | Q3   | C#: something else
```

then a table called answers with something like this

```
id | uid | qid | value
1  | 100 | 1   | true
2  | 100 | 3   | false
3  | 101 | 2   | false
4  | 101 | 3   | true
```

where qif is a FK to the question table, and uid a key to some other user table (not important here)

Now I'd like to generate the following table:

```
uid | Java | Python | C#
100 | true | null   | false
101 | null | false  | true
```

that is, a table that for each user contains all different questions taken from its table, with its column name generated dynamically based on its text (ie. using substring for instance)

My initial approach is the naive one, using something like this:

```
SELECT uid, java
FROM answer
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT a.uid, q.value AS "java"
   FROM answer a
   INNER JOIN question q ON q.id = a.qid
   WHERE q.id=1) java
ON java.uid = u.id

LEFT JOIN
// same for "python", "c#"...
...
```

that is, generating each column by appending to it through a join. This of course works fine when having few items, but I was wondering if there is any alternative approach to do it more generically, without having to do these repetitive LEFT JOINS

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do actually mean generate a "table", or do you mean generate a result set? The former is almost always a bad idea, the latter is usually referred to as a "crosstab" or "pivot" query. _In either case, you cannot generate dynamic fields without using dynamic (constructed) sql queries._

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, first I meant to generate a result and then simply prepend a "CREATE TABLE" on that. So from what you say there's no other way round than repeating JOINS, right?

Comment: Dynamic sql is required, but it doesn't necessarily have to be JOINs specifically; it really depends on the table structure and desired results. Many times, something like this suffices `SELECT ..., SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'alpha' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS alphaTotal, SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'beta' ... FROM ...` I'd look around at answers to previous crosstab and pivot questions to see if you can find one that suits your task.